# Is it possible to make a new column average using a column alias?

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I'm currently trying to work out the difference between two dates, which I've been successful with, however I then want to calculate an average of the column alias I've created.

Currently the code I am trying to use:

```
SELECT actualfinish, actualstart, internalpriority, DATEDIFF(mi, actualstart, actualfinish) AS [date difference], AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, actualstart, actualfinish) AS [AVG date diff]
FROM mytable
WHERE (internalpriority=1) AND (actualfinish IS NOT NULL) AND (actualstart IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY [date difference];
```

Is there even a way to do this? Or am I wasting my time?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you need to do a `GROUP BY` for your `AVG` to work. And as to immediately use the alias, you can't. You either use a CTE, a derived table or just use the whole calculation again:

CTE Method

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  actualfinish, 
            actualstart, 
            internalpriority, 
            DATEDIFF(mi, actualstart, actualfinish) AS [date difference]
    FROM mytable
    WHERE (internalpriority=1) AND (actualfinish IS NOT NULL) AND (actualstart IS NOT NULL)
)
SELECT  actualfinish, 
        actualstart, 
        internalpriority,
        AVG([date difference]) OVER() [AVG date diff]
FROM CTE
ORDER BY [AVG date diff]
```

Derived Table:

```
SELECT  actualfinish, 
        actualstart, 
        internalpriority,
        AVG([date difference]) OVER() [AVG date diff]
FROM (  SELECT  actualfinish, 
                actualstart, 
                internalpriority, 
                DATEDIFF(mi, actualstart, actualfinish) AS [date difference]
    FROM mytable
    WHERE (internalpriority=1) AND (actualfinish IS NOT NULL) AND (actualstart IS NOT NULL)) A
ORDER BY [AVG date diff]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply, I have tried both pieces of code and sadly neither are currently working for me. For the CTE method I'm getting `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column mytable.actualfinish' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` And for the derived table it seems to think the column names are invalid.

Comment: @WillGolledge Oh, right, I left that `AVG` there for mistake. Try again now, please

Comment: That fixed the error thanks, however when the program runs, in the `AVG date diff` column, it still shows the individual difference for each row rather than an average of all the rows.

Comment: Just checked, and the above statement applies for both the CTE & Derived table

Comment: @WillGolledge Well, can you explain what is the result that you want?, the total average?, just one row?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I'm trying to get an average of all the result rows, so in theory every row should have the same value in the `average` column.

Comment: Brilliant it now works, thank you very much for your help, sorry for the mis-understanding. I would Vote Up your answer however I don't have enough rep, either way, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry to keep hassling you, but what actually did adding in the `over()` clause, I have tried googling but with little success

Comment: @WillGolledge Normally, if you want to use an aggregation function (as `AVG`), the rest of the columns on your select that aren't using an aggregation function, need to be declared on a `GROUP BY` clause. This way, for every combination of the values of those columns, you get the `AVG` of the other one, meaning a different average for each combination. The `OVER` (wich was added on SQL Server 2005) lets you define aggregation functions outside the `GROUP BY`, it can be used with `PARTITION BY` if you need that value to change. If defined only as `OVER()`, then it will be for the whole set